# Why do parentheses make a difference when initializing an empty vector?

Tags: c++, stl, compiler-errors

I'm having trouble understanding an error. I'm working with a straightforward map of vectors (keyed by strings and storing vectors of strings):

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > TRouteMarkets;
```

The following code (stripped down),

```
void CFoo::Bar(const char* route, const char* market)
{
    // ...

    TRouteMarkets::key_type key(route);
    TRouteMarkets::mapped_type mapped();
    TRouteMarkets::value_type pair(key, mapped);

    // ...
}
```

produces the following error:

> "Foo.cc", line 518: Error: Could not find a match for std::pair<const std::string, std::vector<std::string>>::pair(const std::string, std::vector<std::string>()) needed in CFoo::Bar(const char*, const char*).

But removing the `()` from mapped, *i.e.*

```
TRouteMarkets::mapped_type mapped;
```

fixes the error. Why? Isn't `mapped` an empty vector of strings in either case?

Comment: Read about [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: We really need an automatic checker for the vexing parse and family. I had a good idea from the question title what this would be, it comes up so often (c:

Comment: This is not the most vexing parse.

Comment: @hmjd - Could you elaborate, perhaps by editing your answer? I'm curious to know the distinction between what I'm reading on Wikipedia, and my code.

Comment: @ecatmur - I'd delete the question, but I guess it might still be useful as a search result for those, like me, who might think the problem has something to do with initializing an empty vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a function declaration:

```
TRouteMarkets::mapped_type mapped();
```

declaring a function named `mapped` that accepts no arguments and returns a `TRouteMarkets::mapped_type`.

Answer (score 5):

You've run into the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) problem.

```
TRouteMarkets::mapped_type mapped();
```

The above line is declaring a function named `mapped` that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `TRouteMarkets::mapped_type`.

With C++11, you can use uniform initialization syntax to avoid this problem.

```
TRouteMarkets::mapped_type mapped{}; // Not a function declaration anymore
```

Comment: Ah, all is clear again; can't believe I've never run into this issue before! Thank you, and apologies to @hmjd and @@JoachimPileborg that only one can be awarded for the answer.

Comment: This is not the most vexing parse.

Comment: The most vexing parse is even more vexing.

Comment: @Praetorian, because it is just a function declaration. The most vexing parse has an argument, treated as an unamed function. Check the article linked in your answer and any article you can find on it.

Comment: @hmjd Isn't this just a simplified case of that? The phrase *most vexing parse* describes a syntactic ambiguity, which is what this is.

Comment: @Praetorian, I don't think so. Vexing yes, but not most vexing. :)

Comment: 'The most vexing parse' as coined by Meyers refers specifically to a  version of this with a non-empty initializer, not just any syntactic ambiguity between variable and function declarations.